# Chessboard Combinatorial Problem

Tags: combinatorics

in how many different ways may eight red and eight green counters be placed on the squares of an 8x8 chessboard so that there are not two counters on any one square and there is on red counter and one green counter in each row and column.

The book I'm using doesn't contain the solution and I tried to find the solution online,but with no luck. is my solution correct?

My strategy is to place the a red counter and then a green counter for each row. There is 8 squares for the first red and 7 for the green. For the second row there is 7 squares for a red and 6 for a green. Eventually I get 8!7!. Is it right?

Answer (score 1):

There are $8!$ ways of placing the red counters. If you place them on
the main diagonal, then the green counters must correspond to a
[derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement). The total number of possibilities will be $8!$
times the 8-th derangement number.

Comment: Sorry I do t know what a derangement is. Can you give a simpler explanation.

Comment: @DeriveFoiler the Wikipedia link is a good place to start.

Comment: Got it. Thanks SO much.

Answer (score 0):

Lord Shark's answer is correct, and you really need the derangements to have an easy solution.

To point out where the $8!7!$ reasoning fails is that when you have the first red on $A1$ and the first green on $A2$, and the second green on $B2$, then you have $7$ options for that second red.